# remainder on division by 9 for a tricky number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What will be the remainder when $ 32^{32^{32}} $ is divided by 9?

I was able to solve this by using the cyclicity of remainders when $2^{2^n}$ is divided by 9. For $n$ =even it gave remainder 7 and for $n$ =odd it gave remainder 4. So using this I worked out the above to get answer as 4.

However, can there be a more concise way possible using some theorem like Fermat's or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler's theorem says that any number coprime to $9$, raised to the sixth power is congruent to $1$ mod $9$. We have that $32$ is coprime to $9$, so $32^6\equiv 1 \mod 9$.

Now, we need to know what the exponent $32^{32}$ is mod $6$. By the chinese remainder theorem, we can reduce to mod $2$ and mod $3$. The exponent is obviously even, so it's congruent to $0$ mod $2$. It then remains to check congruency modulo $3$. We have (working mod $3$):
$$
32^{32} \equiv 2^{32} \equiv (2^2)^{16} \equiv 1^{16} \equiv 1
$$
so that finally we get $32^{32}\equiv 4$ mod $6$.

Back to the original question, this means that for some natural number $n$
$$
32^{32^{32}} = 32^{6n + 4} \equiv 32^4 \equiv 5^4 \mod 9
$$
This is not too difficult to calculate, since $5^2 = 25 \equiv -2$ mod $9$, so $5^4 \equiv (-2)^2 \equiv 4$.

Answer (score 0):

We see that 32/9 leaves a remainder of either $5$ or $(-4)$.

Now we need to find the remainder for $(-4)^{32^{32}}/9$.

Even power for negative numbers gives the same result as for it's positive counterpart, and we see $4^3 = 64$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $9$.

Now we need to find $32^{32}/3$, to see what power we'd see on 4.

$32$ when divided by $3$ leaves a remainder of $2$ or $(-1)$.

$(-1)^{32} = 1$.

Thus, we have the result as $4^1 = 4$.

We can thus solve this without using any of the Fermat/Wilson Theorems.

Answer (score -1):

$32^{32^{32}}=(2^5)^{32^{32}}=(2^{160})^{32}$.

We know that $2^3=-1\pmod 9$. Hence $2^{159}=-1 \pmod 9$

$2^{160}=-2 \pmod 9$ or $2^{160}=7 \pmod 9$. Therefore $2^{160^{32}}=7^{32}$.

Now $7^3=1 \pmod 9$.

Therefore $(7^3)^{10}=1^{10} \pmod 9$ or $7^{30}=1 \pmod 9$.

Hence $7^{32}=49 \pmod 9$ or $7^{32}=4 \pmod 9$.

Hence $32^{32^{32}}=0 \pmod 9$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please have a look at how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) to improve your answer.

Comment: in the second step: you cannot multiply $5$ by $32$, but only after $32^{32}$